# What does the term "box" mean in the context of drivers?

Tags: c, macos, audio, driver, core-audio

Inspecting `NullAudio.c` file from Apple's NullAudio example (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Listings/NullAudio_NullAudio_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013590-NullAudio_NullAudio_c-DontLinkElementID_3)) I found the following description:

```
// The purpose of the NullAudio sample is to provide a bare bones implementations to
// illustrate the minimal set of things a driver has to do. The sample driver has the following
// qualities:
//  - …
//  - a box
//  - …
```

As stated in the title: What is meant by **a box**?

Comment: There is the possibility it literally means A Box, a housing, a casing, something to identify that is a particular model of device and any functionality that box may have.

Comment: Again, to avoid any heavy lifting, it would be worthwhile adding a link to the [Documentation Archive: Core Audio User-Space Driver Examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013590-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: Thanks, I now also added a link in the question.